# Оформление только выбранных товаров из корзины

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно оформлять только те товара, которые выбраны чекбоксом. Пример на озоне.

Пробовал фильтр woocommerce_get_cart_contents, Если уберут галочку с товара, то он совсем удалится из корзины и из сессии тоже.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_contents', function($contents) {
    $checked_products = $_POST['checked_products'];
    foreach ($contents as $key => $content) {
        $product = $content['data'];
        if (in_array($product->get_id(), $checked_products)) {
            unset($contents[$key]);
        }
    }
   return $contents;
});
```

[image: Выбрали 3 товара - в оформлении будет 3 товара]